# What Should Go In A New htaccess File?

Tags: .htaccess

GoDaddy is suggesting that my website has malware. They suggest I review htaccess file...

The file doesn't seem to have much in it... but I guess my website needs it... ? (I'm a layman, by the way).

What should I do? Should I delete all code that is currently in the file? My website has just several pages.

Here is the code currently in the file:

***RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^2693701498/(.*)$ excitation-autographing.php [QSA,L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^8460001373/(.*)$ lucas-leia.php [QSA,L]***

Not sure if that was placed there by whatever hacking bot attacked the website...

Thank you in advance!

[Link](http://www.petsonthemovenyc.com/) to the website.

Comment: That was definitely added by a hack / .htaccess injection.

Comment: Thanks, bud! If I delete all that code, is it safe for file to remain blank, then?

Comment: Should be, however, you need to identify where / why someone was able to inject malicious stuff into your file. Does anyone have your FTP password? Do you have any .php files that accept user input that isn't filtered proper, etc...

Comment: Thanks, Adam. Oh boy - I've got to think about that.No one else has FTP password, no. The contact form uses .php, I believe. Its a contact form generated by GoDaddy, I believe... is it possible that's how the malicious code got through? Through the contact form? This is incredible. Thank you for your help!